# Inject repository into ServiceAuthorizationManager using Unity

Tags: wcf, unity-container, wcf-rest, api-key

I would like to inject a repository (using unity) to an ServiceAuthorizationManager implementation. Is it possible?

```
 public class APIKeyAuthorization : ServiceAuthorizationManager
    {


        private readonly IKeysService _keysService;

        public APIKeyAuthorization(KeysService keysService)
        {
            _keysService = keysService;
        }

        protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
        {
            //var _keysService = new KeysService();


            string key = GetAPIKey(operationContext);

            string endpoint = GetEndpoint(operationContext); //ip address

            if (_keysService.IsValidKey(key, endpoint))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Send back an HTML reply
                CreateErrorReply(operationContext, key);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: give me teh codez. did u try anything ? yes it is possible, overwrite it, and inject it to overriden class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731774.aspx

Comment: the question has been updated with the overwrite class.
I registered the type like this:
container.RegisterType<IKeysService, KeysService>();
container.RegisterType<APIKeyAuthorization>();

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to register `APIKeyAuthorization` with the container. Unity can resolve concrete classes well on its own.
If you want to inject your `APIKeyAuthorization` as another implementation of `ServiceAuthorizationManager` you will have to register that mapping with the container

```
container.RegisterType<ServiceAuthorizationManager, APIKeyAuthorization>();
```

Unity will inject the registered implementation of `IKeyService` (in your case that would be an instance of `KeyService`) into the constructor of `APIAuthorization`.

Try

```
APIAuthorization auth = container.Resolve<APIAuthorization>();
```

And you will see that Unity resolves `IKeyService` for you.

But please don't make the mistake to [abuse Unity as a ServiceLocator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

Instead wire up the container in the [composition root of your application](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) and resolve only the top level object from the container.

Comment: Hi Sebastian. Thanks for your answer. I'm already using a "bootstrapper" to setup the container. Following your approach I have a problem. If I resolve the APIAuthorization it calls the constructor with parameters (what I expect), but if I let the framework do is job, it goes to the constructor without parameters... do you know why?

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira Which framework? Unity will pick the constructor that takes the most arguments for resolution. That's by design. If framework means the WCF infrastructure then that might be different. As far as I know WCF calls default constructors and throws if they are not available. At least that is true for services. Might be the same for other infrastructure components.

Comment: .net framework 4 + Unity 2.0. This seems that it is not resolving anything. I have this at web.config: <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="App.APIKeyAuthorization, App" />

Comment: and if I remove the default ctor (public APIKeyAuthorization()) I get the message: "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira That's WCF doing its work. WCF does not know about Unity when it tries to instantiate the specified `ServiceAuthorizationManager`. There are a couple of questions around asking how to solve that problem using NInject but none of them is answered as far as I can tell. Sorry but I don't have a solution either.

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira The `ServiceAuthorizationElement` is used to create the `ServiceAuthorizationBehavior` which calls `Activator.CreateInstance` to create an instance of the type you specified as `ServiceAuthorizationManager`. Maybe you can derive from those elements to plug Unity into the pipeline at that point.